# Using Apple's iPhone 4S product images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, image-quality, screenshot, iphone

I downloaded [Apple's iPhone 4S product images](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/marketing/index.html#agreement) (log-in required). I'd like to just copy/paste a 640x960 screenshot of my app from my iPhone 4 to the psd file. However the psd file has 4x dimensions. So a simple copy/paste results in a tiny screenshot of my app on this huge iPhone 4S. **What's the best way to work around this?**

I've tried changing the image and canvas sizes but ran into problems with blurry images and copy/paste of my screenshot still resulting in a little tiny image on a giant iPhone. Creating a 4x mockup of my app is far too much work. IMO a 640x960 screenshot will be plenty large and provide plenty of detail especially since this image is destined for the web and I'm being mindful of the file size.

Perhaps I can enlarge my screenshot which will be blurry. But exporting the png might make that blurryness not matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want your screen shot to be blurry, open the screen shot in PhotoShop, then go to image size, increase the size x2 in each dimension, and then choose 'nearest neighbor' as the interpolation option.

The end result will be an image 4 times larger but the pixels will remain aliased and you won't get the blurring.